# Removing zoom in/out from Highmaps

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

I am using Highmaps to plot a map on my webpage. I want to disable any kind of zooming, for ex:

1. Through zoom in zoom out buttons.
2. Through scroll.
3. Pinch to zoom.
4. On touch devices.
5. Multiple clicks to zoom in.

I have tried this:

```
chart:{
   pinchType : 'none',
   zoomType : 'none'
}
```

and this:

```
mapNavigation:{
        enableButton:false,
        enableDoubleClickZoom:false,
        enableDoubleClickZoomTo:false,
        enableMouseWheelZoom:false,
        enableTouchZoom:false
       },
```

but no luck.

Comment: I added your `mapNavigation` options to demo (http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/mapnavigation/doubleclickzoomto/) and it disabled all zooming.

Answer (score 1):

Try this demo

```js
$.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=world-population-density.json&callback=?', function(data) {

  // Initiate the chart
  Highcharts.mapChart('container', {

    title: {
      text: 'Zoom in on country by double click'
    },

    mapNavigation: {
      enabled: false,
    },

    colorAxis: {
      min: 1,
      max: 1000,
      type: 'logarithmic'
    },

    series: [{
      data: data,
      mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
      joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code'],
      name: 'Population density',
      states: {
        hover: {
          color: '#a4edba'
        }
      },
      tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '/km²'
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 500px;
  min-width: 310px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.loading {
  margin-top: 10em;
  text-align: center;
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="max-width: 1000px"></div>
```

jsfiddle demo : http://jsfiddle.net/geogeorge/ssh63xhb/